# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress pod subpath

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a pod that exposes an HTTP service.
This pod has some HTTP endpoints which are available under `/accounts`.
My goal is to access this sub-path via `accounts.example.com`.

For example if the url `accounts.example.com/test` is requested, the nginx ingress should route the request to `/accounts/test` on my pod.

In the nginx ingress documentation I cannot find a use-case with examples like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use rewrite to accomplish your request.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

- Here is an example:

  - Focus on this line: `path: /something(/|$)(.*)`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

---

- Look on the different annotations for the re-write:

[image]
[image]